# Is regex for Hive different from the normal regex?

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using Hive to analyse a web log that looks like this

```
415503 - - [10/Jun/1998:00:48:00 +0000] "GET /english/images/nav_sitemap_off.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 416
```

I used the regex below to load this to the hive table which works fine

```
([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)
```

But if i check for this regex in https://www.regex101.com/, this regex doesn't match with my string.

If i remove some backslashes in the block

```
(-|\\[[^\\]]*\\])
```

it is validated.

I think we have to put \ to escape strings when i comes to regex in Hive? But how do i validate this before creating the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hive uses Java regex syntax. Try http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm for testing purposes.

see [Apache Hive - REGEXColumnSpecification](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-REGEXColumnSpecification) for details.

[image: Test with your input]

Comment: thank you very much! So i setup the regex the normal way adn from the link you provided i can use the Java String regex for the Hive create statement right? :)